# nginx - server doesn't show requested site

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

So I installed nginx on a local Linux Virtual Machine (Ubuntu Server, if it matters) though apt, and created a slightly modified config file for my website following the default site's template:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.local;

    root      /srv/http/mysite.local;
    index     index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    autoindex on;
}
```

I have added the server's IP to my Windows hosts file, like so:

```
192.168.56.103 mysite.local
```

But when I try to insert the site in my browser to access it, I get served the default nginx startup page instead, despite that in its access.log I see it getting a request from `mysite.local` and not `192.168.56.103` (through favicon requests).

I have done the following things already:

- Re-added a symlink from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`
- Deleted the default page symlink from `sites-enabled` (which just returns a 404)
- Renamed the `mysite.local` symlink to `default`
- Refreshed and restarted the nginx server multiple times after each step
- Allowed read and execute access folders leading to the website root, and read access to its contents to user `www-data` with ACL

**EDIT:** result of `sudo nginx -T`

```
nginx: [warn] duplicate extension "woff", content type: "font/woff2", previous content type: "font/woff" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:29
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref:POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-brotli.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-ssl-ct.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_ssl_ct_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_ssl_ct_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/avif                            avif;
    image/png                             png;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/webp                            webp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;

    font/woff                             woff;
    font/woff2                            woff;

    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics        odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation    odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet     ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text            odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation    pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet    xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/wasm                      wasm;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.local:
server {
    #Server access info
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mysite.local;

    #Website file root
        root    /srv/http/mysite.local;
        index   index.php;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    autoindex on;
}
```

Comment: Check the output of `nginx -T`; check the `curl -H 'Host: mysite.local' http://<your_ip>/` result.

Comment: @IvanShatsky `nginx -T` (without root) says it can't access `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and `/run/nginx.pid`.
curl command just returns the HTML for a 404 page

Comment: `nginx -T` should be executed from the `root` user (or via `sudo`). Do your have an `index.php` file under your webserver root folder (`/srv/http/mysite.local`)?

Comment: @IvanShatsky, I added the result in my question, and yes, I do have an `index.php` file in that folder.

Comment: Since your have the only single server block, it should act as a [default server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) serving any request appearing at your network interface plain HTTP port 80. Besides you don't have a PHP-FPM handler and should receive an uninterpreted PHP code in response, I don't see any reason of not serving this file returning HTTP 404 Not Found.